# Minecraft Java creating function to continue running until a certain circumstance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing Minecraft Java 1.18.2 with very few mods, and already started building something large in creative mode, but it happens to be in an icy biome I would rather it not be in. I was hoping the functions command would be a possible solution to remove the ice/icy biome completely. I'm just not sure how to set up the command so it checks whether a block belongs in that biome, and then replaces that block with a stone block. That would mean all x, y, and z coordinates will have to be considered. If the function could be made so it continues to replace the icy biome blocks with stone blocks until a point where there are none touching it, that would be amazing!

I have already tried commands that replace blocks one by one with specific coordinates as well as manually change the blocks. I also read [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition)), but am having a little difficulty coming to a more specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot detect biomes specifically (in 1.18 that is, in 1.19.3 we got `execute if biome`), making a "flood fill" system that replaces all connected blocks of a certain type is very doable.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, all with advantages and disadvantages.

1. **Using entities** as markers for where you've changed a block last.

   - (+) Allows for "asynchronous" execution, e.g. limiting how many blocks are replaced per tick to prevent lag
   - (+) can be done using commandblocks, no datapack / functions needed, but still possible to be used
   - (-) requires a lot of entities, which itself can cause lag
   - (+) if set up correctly can continue to work in unloaded chunks, once loaded.
2. **Using functions** to keep execution context

   - (+/-) Runs everything in a single tick. This means it's instantaneous, but if there is a lot of blocks that one tick might take a while, so it would create one big lagspike. This might be preferable over the other solution.
   - (+) doesn't require any entities to be created
   - ((-)) Needs to be set up through a datapack. Which is not difficult, but a barrier for some, also because it needs to be added to the file system of the server.
   - (-) only works in loaded chunks
   - (-) might run into issues with the maximum command in a function limit. Luckily that's a gamerule and we can modify that and set it to a much higher number. It's also easy to spot, as the command would be called from chat and tell us how many functions it ran.

If you're able to use a datapack, you have the advantage of being able to create a [block tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag#Block_tags) to make it easier to replace a set of blocks instead of defining every block individually.

---

### Using a datapack and functions

*I'll focus on this solution in this answer, as it's easier to make than the other one. If you'd like to know the entity solution, let me know and I can add it.*

Related: [How to create a datapack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack)

I'll be using `ff` as the namespace (for `flood fill`) in this solution. This means that all these files need to be placed inside the `world/datapacks/FloodFill/data/ff/` folder.

First, let's make the blocktag with all the blocks we want to replace. I'll add ice, packed_ice and snow to it.

`/tags/blocks/replace.json`

```
{
  "values": [
    "minecraft:ice",
    "minecraft:packed_ice",
    "minecraft:snow_block"
  ]
}
```

Next we want to make the function file to run the replacement process. It will set its own block position to be stone, then check in all 6 cardinal directions whether the block there is one of the blocks defined in the block tag and if so, it will run itself again.

`/functions/run.mcfunction`

```
setblock ~ ~ ~ stone

execute positioned ~1 ~ ~ if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
execute positioned ~-1 ~ ~ if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
execute positioned ~ ~ ~1 if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
execute positioned ~ ~ ~-1 if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
execute positioned ~ ~1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ #ff:replace run function ff:run
```

Now, to start the system all you need to do is run the function at any block that is adjacent to at least one of the defined blocks.